# Image preloader problems when file not in root

Tags: javascript

I am working with some existing code and there is a preloader which loads some images for the navigation rollover state.  It looks like this:

```
<body onload="MM_preloadImages('Images/Home-over.png','Images/Signup-over.png','Images/Costs-over.png','Images/Team-over.png','Images/Process-over.png','Images/Scholarships-over.png','Images/Login-over.png','Images/FAQ-over.png','Images/Contact-over.png','Images/About-over.png')">
```

An example of one of the nav items using the above is below:

```
 <div id="Layer-15" class="Contact"  > <a href="contact.html"><img src="Images/Contact.png" alt="Contact" name="Contact" width="98" height="56" border="0" class="pngimg" id="Contact" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Contact','','Images/Contact-over.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></div>
```

Now all of the above is in the root folder.

When I go one folder deep, the nav breaks:

My code looks exactly the same as that posted above except that I prefix each reference to an image with '../', e.g. '../Images/Home-over.png' to send it back to the root folder first.

Unfortunately this does not work.

As nothing else is broken it seems to me that the images are not getting pre-loaded and this will most likely be because the image path is wrong.

However I'm not sure how it can be or how I go about figuring out the correct path?

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why not give a try not using `../Images/Home-over.png` ? ? instead use just `Images/Home-over.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem behind this was that the entire page code was getting duplicated due to a duplicate 'includes' statement in my php and this then prevented the styling of the nav bar.